# Load parquet folders to spark dataframe based on condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have directory which has folders based on the date and running date is part of the folder name. I have a daily spark job in which i need to load last 7 days files on any given day.

Unfortunately the folder contains other files as well to try partition discovery.

I have files as below format.

`prefix-yyyyMMdd/`

How to load folders within last 7 days in one shot.?

Since it is running date, i cannot have predefined regex that can be used to load the data, as i have to consider month and year changes.

I have couple of brute force solutions

1. to load all the data into 7 dataframes and do unionAll with all 7, to get one dataframe from 7 dataframes. ***This looks performance inefficient, but not a entirely bad one***
2. Load entire folder and do where condition on column that has the date.
   ***This looks storage heavy, as the folder contains years worth of data***

Both doesn't look performance efficient and considering each file data it self is huge, i would like to know if there are any better solutions.

Is there a better way to do it.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DataFrameReader](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader) methods can take multiple paths, e.g.

`spark.read.parquet("prefix-20190704", "prefix-20190703", ...)`